# I have a better answer for a question that has been protected. What can I do?

Tags: support, answers

There is a question that has been protected, but I would also like to answer as I think my answer can really add to that. 
Is there a way to answer a protected question?

Comment: It seems one needs a certain amount of reputation before being able to post an answer, yet [the description](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) doesn't say how much. What question is it by the way?

Comment: mm I can actually do it now. strange. anyway I read the question again and I think Iøm going to create a new one as I don't think that is asking the exact same

Comment: @ChristianRau: Hmmm...  There probably ought to be a link to where question protection is described in detail.  If you search the help center for "protect", you can read more on [this page](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators).  Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: Do you have a link to the question, Maurizio?

Comment: This was the question, but it works now... http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/871/what-does-the-woman-from-the-future-mean-when-she-says-shes-in-insurance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A protected question is a way the moderators and higher rep users can make sure a post that is getting a lot of attention, say a popular question about a new movie, doesn't get riddled with spam.

The protected moniker disallows anyone below ***10*** reputation from posting anything on the question.  This is so that low rep users can still post a decent answer, but prevents newer accounts typically used for spam and other nonsense cannot.

Seeing your meta rep at 146 tells me that it was some kind of glitch that you couldn't post.  If this occurs again, try to get screenshots so that we can bring this to the correct party to get it fixed.